# Truncate on first non-printable character

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to use `std::regex` to truncate on the first non-printable character.

I tried

```
  std::string ExtractPrintableString(const std::string& message) {
    std::regex trim_nonprintable_regex("([[:print:]]+).*") 
    std::smatch matched_message;
    std::regex_search(message, matched_message, trim_nonprintable_regex);

    return matched_message[1].str()
  }
```

But I am not getting the expected result.

Ex:

If I pass `"\r\t\r\t\r\t\ruessw7cr9jhmdiy"` it should return empty string.

If I pass `"asd\r\tdfvdfv"` then it should return `asd` only.

Comment: You need to either anchor the start of your regex using `^` or use `std::regex_match` rather than `std::regex_search`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 1) match at the start of string by adding a `^` at the start and 2) by replacing the `([[:print:]]+).*` pattern with just `[[:print:]]*`:

```cpp
std::string ExtractPrintableString(const std::string& message) {
    std::regex trim_nonprintable_regex("^[[:print:]]*");
    std::smatch matched_message;
    std::regex_search(message, matched_message, trim_nonprintable_regex);

    return matched_message[0].str();
  }
```

Note that in this case, there is no capturing group, so you need to return `matched_message[0].str()`.

See the [online C++ demo](https://ideone.com/7lYLCt).

*Pattern details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:print:]]*` - zero or more printable chars (that are only matched at the start of string due to `^`).

Answer (score 2):

In `std::regex trim_nonprintable_regex("([[:print:]]+).*")`  the `+` means that at least 1 character. So it will never lead to an empty string. Change it to `*` ant it will work. Also you forgot some `;`-s

```
std::string ExtractPrintableString(const std::string& message) {
    std::regex trim_nonprintable_regex("([[:print:]]*).*");
    std::smatch matched_message;
    std::regex_search(message, matched_message, trim_nonprintable_regex);
    return matched_message[1].str();
}
```